Can new building's pier foundations be placed too close to the adjacent ones? (Risk of horizontal pressure under final load?)
We have a house (as it turned out, on stone "wall" foundations) adjacent to which a larger one is being built.
Contrary to the officially sanctified provisional plans, the developer's structural engineer based the new building on concrete piers.
The piers (they have rectangular facets) were placed - in accordance with the final plan - right next to the foundations of the neighbouring buildings, including ours, with efforts made to allow the connecting new and old foundations to slide vertically more independently.
I heard (from professional sources) there may be a risk in such cases, potentially occurring well after the piers will have begun to bear the full load of the new building, that some slow shape/positional (?) changes of the piers may cause horizontal pressure on the adjacent foundations, implying potential damages to the walls of the pre-existing buildings themselves.
Is that a realistic risk?

In the US and commonly other places, any new building permit has to follow a set of regulations and codes regarding protecting adjacent neighboring buildings during and after construction, even if the two buildings are not bordering each other.
Depending on the type and size of the building, the new construction may have to shore up the existing foundation with pilons or retaining structures.
One of the first requirements is that a line projecting 45 degrees from the bottom of the new footing should not cross any existing structure unless it is reinforced using the methods recommended in the soils report.

FWIW, I thought the rule was 45 degrees from the bottom of the foundation (the top of the footing).

It's actually the cone of influence, and it is from the bottom of any footing, mat foundation, grade beam, etc.

Ahh. I've just looked at pictures. The cone of influence starts at the top of level where the support engages with the ground, spreading down, (and the bottom of the footing spreading up). In soft soil on a pillar on a broad foot, only the bottom of the foot engages. That's not what the ground or footings are like where I am, and where I am the footing engages from the top of the footing.

I guess we are talking the same thing, just using different words. The idea is a simplified version of stress distribution in a continuum homogenous media. A point load will influence a cone downward, a long line load will open in a prism downward and a square will have 45-degree sidelines with round corners.
